# increase all array's indices by a number

Tags: bash

There is an array:

```
bash-5.2$ arr=(a b c d e f)
bash-5.2$ paste <(printf "%s\n" "${!arr[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}")
0   a
1   b
2   c
3   d
4   e
5   f
```

I need to increase indices by 2 to get output:

```
2   a
3   b
4   c
5   d
6   e
7   f
```

Is there a way to easily increase all indices by two?

Comment: are you looking to increase the number from the `paste/printf`? or are you looking to modify the actual array indices?

Comment: I wonder what is the purpose of this. Looks weird

Comment: `arr=([2]=a b c d e f)`?

Comment: The [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.

Comment: @Cyrus you should post that as an answer (assuming OP has access to the original statement to populate the array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the objective is to renumber the array indices, one (brute force) idea:

```
$ arr=(a b c d e f)
$ arr2=(x x "${arr[@]}")
$ arr=("${arr2[@]}")
$ unset arr[0] arr[1]

$ paste <(printf "%s\n" "${!arr[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}")
2       a
3       b
4       c
5       d
6       e
7       f

$ typeset -p arr
declare -a arr=([2]="a" [3]="b" [4]="c" [5]="d" [6]="e" [7]="f")
```

Then again, if OP has the original statement for populating the array then just modify said statement, eg:

```
$ arr=(x x a b c d e f)
$ unset arr[0] arr[1]

$ paste <(printf "%s\n" "${!arr[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}")
2       a
3       b
4       c
5       d
6       e
7       f

$ typeset -p arr
declare -a arr=([2]="a" [3]="b" [4]="c" [5]="d" [6]="e" [7]="f")
```

Comment: Nice brute forcing ^^